# How to format the labels of choices in a choice field from a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to change the text shown in the choices of a Django form select Choice Field. Here's some example code:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('T1', 'Thing 1'),
    ('T2', 'Thing 2')
)

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select(),
        choices = CHOICES,
    )
```

I'm not sure if any other code is required to solve the problem, but when I render this form into the template, the values of CHOICES will be shown in the choice field dropdown. What I want is to put both the key and the value as what is shown in the dropdown while still equaling the key in the back end. Like this:

```
Field:
--------------
|           v|
--------------
--------------
|T1 - Thing 1|
|T2 - Thing 2|
--------------
```

Is there a way to have this formatting done in the forms.py code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is probably to simply **create a different `choices` list**  dynamically:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('T1', 'Thing 1'),
    ('T2', 'Thing 2')
)

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select(),
        choices = [(k, '{} - {}'.format(k, v)) for k, v in CHOICES],
    )
```

So here we create a second list, with *list comprehension*, that instead of `('T1', 'Thing 1')`, contains `('T1', 'T1 - Thing 1')` as item. We do *not* alter the `CHOICES` tuple, we only construct a new list to feed to the `ChoiceField`.

Comment: You forgot the second parentheses after format(k, v), but other than that this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JerryBi: arrrggh... yes. Fixed now :)